# How to make Thunderbird open links in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I'm trying to use Thunderbird again, but I can't make it use Firefox to open links. I'm using KDE and Firefox is my default browser. I tried the network.protocol-handler method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open links in thunderbird so that they will open firefox or chrome or opera, you open preferences, attachments, and click on use other and navigate to the browser that you want to use.

Comment: I have already tried that, but there is nothing to select. http://goo.gl/KafD

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but I decided to use Opera for mail, instead of Thunderbird, so will no longer testing other options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that thunderbird uses sensible-browser, that actually tests for the following alternatives: gnome-www-browser and x-www-browser; so what you need to do is manage your altenatives with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

And the choose Firefox for those.

Probably you'd only need to update x-www-browser since you're using KDE.